# Laravel Join Query gives Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel-4

I get results with join query but in view when I want to show it, it says: trying to get property of non object. I am working over a simple blogging system and I am trying to get blogs from following friends. Here is my view:

```
@foreach($blogposts as $posts)
       <h4><a href="">{{ $posts->title }}</a></h4>

@endforeach
```

I am sure the problem is at view but I added my controller too, maybe needed and here is my controller:

```
    $posts=DB::table('following')
    ->join('page_posts', 'following.p_id', '=', 'page_posts.p_id')
    ->select('page_posts.*')
    ->where('u_id','=',Auth::User()->id)
    ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
    ->get();
        return View::make('index')->with('blogposts',$posts);
```

Help me with this please.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: it doesn't show the line but when i tested, the foreach is ok but as example when i type {{ $posts->p_id }} i see the error, i mean when i want to retrive something

Comment: Note that laravel 3, 4, and 5 are all completely different from each other.  Please tag only with the version you are actually using.

Comment: i edited the question, now u can see what my problem really is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used eloquent to solve this means that my controller should be like this:

```
$posts=following::join('page_posts', 'following.p_id', '=', 'page_posts.p_id')
->select('page_posts.*')
->where('u_id','=',Auth::User()->id)
->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
->get();
    return View::make('index')->with('blogposts',$posts);
```

The problem solved. I posted the answer, because someone else maybe needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to pass the values as like this.

```
return View::make('index',array('blogposts'=>$posts));
```

Comment: have you tried to print it just before the @foreach `<?php echo "<pre>";print_r($blogposts):exit;?>` which is i usually do. When the result is empty it will through the non-object error.

Comment: yes i tried the result i not empty it contains everything but i don't know what the problem is

Comment: can you place the result that you got while print the array? So that can guess what may be the error.